# Localization with LocalizedStrings in Xaml - Binding value to the binding string

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, localization

I'm on a question-spree!

I want to know, when binding objects to an ItemsControl, how can I bind a textbox to LocalizedStrings using the current path in de ItemsSource?

Code will clarify, I hope:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Hours}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.DayName, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Style="{StaticResource App_Content_Grid_Bold}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource App_Content_Grid_Subtle}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The problem is, DayName does not exist in LocalizedStrings but it's value does.
How can I parse it's value into this binding context before the binding itself is applied?

Something like: `{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.[DayName], Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}`?